# Find the function $y(x)$ with the property that $y(x)$ has a horizontal tangent line

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

This is a calculus problem I've been struggling on:

"Find the function $y(x)$ with the property that $y(x)$ has a horizontal tangent line at the point $(1,-2)$ and $\frac{d^2y}{dx^2}=2x+5$.

So, I somewhat understand it. I think I need to do:
$y'(x) = x^2 + 5x + c_1$

and then

$y = \frac{1}{3}x^3 + \frac{5}{2}x^2 + c_1x + c_2$

The problem I have is, how do I find $c_1$? I think $c_2$ would be $-2$, from looking at my notes, but I'm still not sure.

Edit:
Ah, thanks, I think I figured it out!

Comment: @Kaster You might want to read the question again.

Answer (score 0):

$$y'(1)=0$$

That's what a horizontal line means... It's slope is $0$. Derivative represents slope.

$$y(1)=-2$$

The curve passes through it.